# OPAM: Can I work on different switches at the same time in different shells?

Tags: opam

This question is addressed in OPAM FAQ [1], but both solutions provided do not work with OPAM v.1.2.2, as `env` and `exec` commands are both unknown. How can I run a single command from the different switch?

[1] https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/2.0/FAQ.html#Can-I-work-on-different-switches-at-the-same-time-in-different-shells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the FAQ for opam 2.0. Here it is for opam 1.2: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/FAQ.html#Can-I-work-on-different-switches-at-the-same-time-in-different-shells

> ***Can I work on different switches at the same time in different
>   shells ?***
>
> Yes. Use one of:
>
> ```
> eval $(opam config env --switch <switch>)        # for the current
> shell opam config exec --switch <switch> -- <command>  # for one command
> ```
>
> This only affects the environment.